# Python ABC not working properly in Python 2.7.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why can I do this?

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractClass(object):

    _metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def foo():
        pass


    @abstractmethod
    def bar():
        pass

class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass):
    pass


a = AbstractClass()
nb = ConcreteClass()
```

There is no error. Everything runs perfectly. Why can I instantiate an abtract class and why can I instantiate an object of ConcreteClass though it did not implement abstract methods?

Comment: Hm, could that be a missing `_` in the beginning of `_metaclass__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `_`

```
__metaclass__ = ABCMeta
```